# ¿Cómo distinguir las intenciones en los textos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Tengo una dataframe con texto y me gustaria classificarlo entre preguntas abiertas preguntas y títulos de la sección de preguntas.

```
    Questions
5   Consumer Personality
11  Consumer Intentions
22  Media Consumption
27  Name (Optional)
33  Feedback / Comments
34  Email (Optional)
37  What is the name of your nearest airport?
38  Where was your most recent destination?
43  Please state your purpose for business travel
47  Leisure Purpose Travel
```

En efecto, ciertos textos corresponden a titulos de sections:

```
Consumer Personality    Section
5   Consumer Personality    Section
6   What is your preference of hotel check-in?  Multiple Choice
7   What is your preference of payment during Chec...   Multiple Choice
8   What is your preference of hotel cancellation ...   Multiple Choice
9   What is your preference of the guest policy?    Multiple Choice
10  What is your preference of the concierge service?   Multiple Choice
```

Mientras que `Email (Optional)` sólo está preguntando por el email de la persona.

En el ejemplo las categorias reales son:

```
    Questions    QTypes
5   Consumer Personality    Section
11  Consumer Intentions    Section
22  Media Consumption    Section
27  Name (Optional)    Pregunta abierta
33  Feedback / Comments    Pregunta abierta
34  Email (Optional)    Pregunta abierta
37  What is the name of your nearest airport?    Pregunta abierta
38  Where was your most recent destination?    Pregunta abierta
43  Please state your purpose for business travel    Pregunta abierta
47  Leisure Purpose Travel    Section
```

Comment: La pregunta como que esta incompleta no.. tenes un dataframe.. en que lenguaje? luego de ello, queres lograr esto.. en que lenguaje? luego, que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Que intentaste?